# Overlap graphs with figurefactory

Tags: python, plot, graph, plotly, overlap

I am trying to plot some finance graphs and I used the plotly libraries for it.

I am quite new to this, so had to look for a way to do it, and wanted to do it offline, so I found this way:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import datetime
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
import plotly
from plotly import figure_factory as ff
import os

yf.pdr_override()


class Stock:
    #We need a constructor to get all the data when we create the class
    def __init__(self, name): #This needs a string as argument to work
        self.name = name
        #If we already have the sotcks data we don't download it again
        if os.path.exists('stock_prices_yahoo/' + name + '.csv'):
            self.df = pd.read_csv('stock_prices_yahoo/' + name + '.csv')
        else:
            start_date = '1950-01-01'
            end_date = datetime.date.today()
            df = web.get_data_yahoo(name, start_date, end_date)
            df.to_csv('stock_prices_yahoo/' + name + '.csv')

    def plot_stock(self): #This will print a plot of the stock prices
        fig = ff.create_candlestick(self.df.Open, self.df.High, self.df.Low, self.df.Close, dates = self.df.Date)
        fig['layout'].update({
        'title': self.name + ' prices',
        'yaxis': {'title': 'Price'},
        'xaxis': {'title': 'Date'},
        })
        plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename = self.name + '-candlestick.html', validate = True)
AAPL = Stock('AAPL')
AAPL.plot_stock()
```

The point is I want to overlap some moving averages on it, and, after looking for it around the whole internet, peaple always do it via matplotlib.
Is there any way to do it with figure_factory?

Comment: Present a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the sake of reproducability

Comment: I am sorry, I wanted to be too simple, I think, and lacked enough code, my bad.